# SQL query to return a row even if not found, with at least in parameters

Tags: oracle

I would like to write a SQL query (oracle)
to know if an operation (identified by ope.ope_operationid)
has at least an operation of a certain type (opt.opt_id), and if it does not, to show that it doesn't in the results.

For example, I have this operation LAA351BP (I know this one exists in base),
and I would like to know if it has at least an operation type which id is 3781.
If it has, print everything, if it hasn't, print the operationid
and something like 'not found' next to it

Is nvl the function to use ? It seems I can't get it to work properly.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ope.ope_operationid,
ser.ser_code,
opt.opt_code,
ost.ost_code
FROM    od_operation ope, 
od_service_type ser,
od_operation_type opt,
od_status_type ost,
od_equipment_type eqt,
WHERE   ope.ser_id = ser.ser_id
AND     opt.opt_id = ope.opt_id
AND     ost.ost_id = ope.ost_id
AND     ope.opt_id = 3781
AND     ope.ope_operationid = 'LAA351BP'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should start using standard JOIN syntax. Apart from being more readable (at least in my opinion) it also protects you from accidental cartesian joins if you forget the actual join condition in the WHERE clause. Plus it is portable across nearly all DBMS as opposed to the clunky `(+)` syntax used by Oracle (which also has some limitations that the JOIN syntax does not have)

Here is the query re-written using explicit (instead of implicit) joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ope.ope_operationid,
       ser.ser_code,
       opt.opt_code,
       ost.ost_code
FROM od_operation ope, 
   LEFT JOIN od_service_type ser ON ope.ser_id = ser.ser_id
   LEFT JOIN od_operation_type opt ON opt.opt_id = ope.opt_id
   LEFT JOIN od_status_type ost ON ost.ost_id = ope.ost_id
   LEFT JOIN od_equipment_type eqt ON ????????
WHERE ope.opt_id = 3781
AND   ope.ope_operationid = 'LAA351BP'
```

**Edit**

The missing join condition on `od_equipment_type` is exactly the reason why the JOIN syntax is preferred. If the trailing comma in the original SQL is removed, the statement would create an unwanted cartesian join which might have a severe impact on the server if the involved tables are big.

With the JOIN syntax you will always get a syntax error which prevents you from such typos. Using implicit joins will only give you an error when you leave a comma in the FROM list, but never if you miss a join condition in the `WHERE`

Comment: +1. You've got a random `od_equipment_type eqt` in the middle, but then so does the OP...

Comment: @Ben: thanks. I added a comment explaining why this is exactly the situation that shows the advantages of using explicit JOINs