# SQL Sum of Sums

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum

I have calculated the sum of a count in different tables. This is done twice, once for each `performanceID`. Now I want to get the sum of the two sums.

Below is the code for the two sums that I do at the moment:

```
    SELECT SUM((COUNT (BookingID) * CategoryPrice)) AS TotalAmount
    FROM Booking, Production
    WHERE Booking.PerformanceID IN(SELECT PerformanceID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '1')
    and Production.ProductionID IN 
    (SELECT ProductionID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '1') 
    GROUP BY BookingID, CategoryPrice
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM((COUNT (BookingID) * CategoryPrice)) AS TotalAmount
    FROM Booking, Production
    WHERE Booking.PerformanceID IN(SELECT PerformanceID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '2')
    and Production.ProductionID IN 
    (SELECT ProductionID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '2')
     GROUP BY BookingID, CategoryPrice
```

The results I get are:

```
TOTALAMOUNT
-----------
         70
         60
```

How do I sum up the two sums here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm never going to compete with the FGITW but I have to say something about this query...

If we add whitespace I hope you'll see what I mean:

```
SELECT SUM( (COUNT(BookingID) * CategoryPrice) ) AS TotalAmount
  FROM Booking
     , Production
 WHERE Booking.PerformanceID IN ( SELECT PerformanceID 
                                   FROM Performance 
                                  WHERE PerformanceID = '1')
   AND Production.ProductionID IN ( SELECT ProductionID FROM Performance 
                                     WHERE PerformanceID = '1') 
 GROUP BY BookingID, CategoryPrice
 UNION ALL
SELECT SUM( (COUNT(BookingID) * CategoryPrice)) AS TotalAmount
  FROM Booking
     , Production
 WHERE Booking.PerformanceID IN ( SELECT PerformanceID 
                                    FROM Performance 
                                   WHERE PerformanceID = '2')
   AND Production.ProductionID IN ( SELECT ProductionID 
                                      FROM Performance 
                                     WHERE PerformanceID = '2')
 GROUP BY BookingID, CategoryPrice
```

Breaking the query down the *only* reason that you got two rows returned were the analytic functions and the union all.

1. You're doing a [cartesian join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join) between `booking` and `production`, this means that you multiply the number of rows in each by each other.
2. Your sub-selects on `performance` are returning one value, which is already known. There's no reason to do them at all.
3. You're implicitly converting numbers into strings and back into numbers again.
4. You're scanning a table or index 8 times here!

It appears as though you want the total amount taken for each performance in which case your query can be simplified to the following:

```
SELECT SUM(bookings * CategoryPrice)
  FROM ( SELECT CategoryPrice , count(*) as bookings
           FROM Booking b
           JOIN performance per
             ON p.performanceid =  per.performanceid
           JOIN Production p
             ON p.productionid = per.productionid
          WHERE p.performanceid in (1, 2)
          GROUP BY CategoryPrice
                )
```

Please note the explicit join syntax, this has been around for a few decades, makes things a lot clearer and [helps stop mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10263148/458741). This query will do two range scans, one of `booking` and one of `production`, assuming you have indexes on `performanceid` on both tables. It'll also do a unique scan of `performance` assuming that `performanceid` is the primary key of this table.

As an explanation of what this does, now I've finally managed to get your schema correct! We select the two performances, `1` and `2`. We then select every production related to those performances and every booking related to those productions. You may be able to simplify this further depending on what table `categoryprice` is in. We then get the number of bookings per `categoryprice` and sum the product of these to give you the total value.

As a bit of advice, I would *always* recommend understanding what values you expect to be returned from a query *before* you accept that your query is correct. The very best can and do make mistakes. Being able to catch them because you can see that the returned values are incorrect will help.

#### Further Reading:

- [Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) - Wikipedia
- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) - Coding Horror
- [In Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) - Tech on the Net

Comment: What do you use to format that query? :-) Your query look neat

Comment: @MichaelBuen, the space bar :p. I work with hundreds of thousands of lines of code. I make the devs write code that's readable or we don't have a chance.

Comment: That's cumbersome ;-) I thought you are using some automation tool

Comment: i tried this but the way you wrote it, says that production has performanceId in it. However, i dont have it like that. i have productionId in performace table.

Comment: Thanks mate, worked like a charm. just had to change the two joins around because of the way i have my tables linked. but all works now. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Davide, I've updated the answer again. I'm not doing too well this morning.

Comment: Nearly there mate... :D... just posting the actual working version, just so u can update your answer -                             SELECT SUM(bookings * CategoryPrice)
  FROM ( SELECT CategoryPrice , count(*) as bookings
           FROM Booking b
           JOIN performance per
             ON b.performanceid =  per.performanceid
           JOIN Production p
             ON per.productionid = p.productionid          
          WHERE per.performanceid in (1, 2, 3, 4)
          GROUP BY CategoryPrice
                )

Answer (score 0):

Use sub sql, and sum TotalAmount

```
SELECT SUM(TotalAmount)
   ( SELECT SUM((COUNT (BookingID) * CategoryPrice)) AS TotalAmount
        FROM Booking, Production
        WHERE Booking.PerformanceID IN(SELECT PerformanceID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '1')
        and Production.ProductionID IN 
        (SELECT ProductionID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '1') 
        GROUP BY BookingID, CategoryPrice
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SUM((COUNT (BookingID) * CategoryPrice)) AS TotalAmount
        FROM Booking, Production
        WHERE Booking.PerformanceID IN(SELECT PerformanceID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '2')
        and Production.ProductionID IN 
        (SELECT ProductionID FROM Performance WHERE PerformanceID = '2')
Group By CategoryPrice)
```

Comment: this will give me an error saying that it needs a group by function.